# C# List Join List And Filter From Another List

Tags: c#, linq

Need some help constructing proper LINQ query with join.

I have the following setup:

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string StudentEmail { get; set; }
}

public class Enrolled
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

public class Dropped
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}


// Populating the List.
// Setup the Student List
List<Student> lstStudents = new List<Student>();

var John = new Student()
{
    StudentEmail = "john@stanford.edu",
    StudentName = "John Wayne"
};

var Maya = new Student()
{
    StudentEmail = "maya@stanford.edu",
    StudentName = "Maya Agnes"
};

var Eric = new Student()
{
    StudentEmail = "eric@stanford.edu",
    StudentName = "Eric James"
};

var Ellen = new Student()
{
    StudentEmail = "ellen@stanford.edu",
    StudentName = "Ellen Page"
};

lstStudents.Add(John);
lstStudents.Add(Maya);
lstStudents.Add(Eric);
lstStudents.Add(Ellen);

// Setup the Enrolled List
List<Enrolled> lstEnrolled = new List<Enrolled>();

// John
var JohnMath = new Enrolled() { Student = John, Subject = "Math" };
var JohnScience = new Enrolled() { Student = John, Subject = "Science" };
var JohnEnglish = new Enrolled() { Student = John, Subject = "English" };

// Maya
var MayaMath = new Enrolled() { Student = Maya, Subject = "Math" };

// Eric
var EricMath = new Enrolled() { Student = Eric, Subject = "Math" };
var EricScience = new Enrolled() { Student = Eric, Subject = "Science" };
var EricSocial = new Enrolled() { Student = Eric, Subject = "Social" };

// Ellen
var EllenMath = new Enrolled() { Student = Ellen, Subject = "Math" };
var EllenScience = new Enrolled() { Student = Ellen, Subject = "Science" };
var EllenEnglish = new Enrolled() { Student = Ellen, Subject = "English" };
var EllenSocial = new Enrolled() { Student = Ellen, Subject = "Social" };

lstEnrolled.Add(JohnMath);
lstEnrolled.Add(JohnScience);
lstEnrolled.Add(JohnEnglish);
lstEnrolled.Add(MayaMath);
lstEnrolled.Add(EricMath);
lstEnrolled.Add(EricScience);
lstEnrolled.Add(EricSocial);
lstEnrolled.Add(EllenMath);
lstEnrolled.Add(EllenScience);
lstEnrolled.Add(EllenEnglish);
lstEnrolled.Add(EllenSocial);

// Setup the Dropped List
List<Dropped> lstDropped = new List<Dropped>();

// John dropped Math
var JohnDropMath = new Dropped() { Student = John, Subject = "Math" };

// Eric dropped Social
var EricDropSocial = new Dropped() { Student = Eric, Subject = "Social" };

// Ellen Dropped Math
var EllenDropMath = new Dropped() { Student = Ellen, Subject = "Math" };

lstDropped.Add(JohnDropMath);
lstDropped.Add(EricDropSocial);
lstDropped.Add(EllenDropMath);
```

What I am trying to achieve is get a list of all students, and the subjects they are enrolled in one line, like:

```
Student     Subjects
-------     ----------------------------------
John        English, Science
Maya        Math
Eric        Math, Science
Ellen       English, Science, Social
```

I have constructed the following so far:

```
var StudentsAndCurrentSubjects = (from st in lstStudents
                                  join en in lstEnrolled 
                                      on st.StudentName equals en.Student.StudentName
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      st.StudentName,
                                      en.Subject
                                  })
                                  .ToList();
```

But it is giving me the result per person per subject.

I hit a wall on how to exclude the dropped items from the list.

I am thinking of traversing the dropped list, like:

```
foreach(d in lstDropped) 
{
    // Logic to Remove it from the StudentsAndCurrentSubjects 
}
```

But I feel that it is inefficient (especially if I have lots of rows).

I also do not know how to join the subjects in one line.

Looking for some help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to first remove dropped subjects from enrolled list. then group by student.
note that we have list for each student, that it has `Student` and `Subject` as its fields, we just select the name of first student from each (as they all the same) and join the subjects together.

```
var result = lstEnrolled.Where(e => !lstDropped.Any(d => d.Student == e.Student && d.Subject == e.Subject))  //omit dropped courses
     .GroupBy(x => x.Student) // group results by students
     .Select(x => new {
            Name = x.First().Student.StudentName.Split(' ').First(), 
            Subjects = string.Join(", ", x.Select(e => e.Subject)) 
       }).ToArray();
```

for printing:

```
foreach(var x in result)
Console.WriteLine($"{x.Name}\t{x.Subjects}");
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QKdgZr)

Comment: Good solution.  2 thoughts: #1 possible to use `Name = x.Key.StudentName` for the name.  #2 students with no classes will not appear in the output, which may be desired.

Comment: Well OP explicitly has defined what he wants for output.

Comment: I Added a live demo to my code, that you can check.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The join is correct, you just need to actually apply the grouping you want:

```
var StudentsAndCurrentSubjects = (from st in lstStudents
                                  join en in lstEnrolled 
                                      on st.StudentName equals en.Student.StudentName
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      st.StudentName,
                                      en.Subject
                                  })
                                  .GroupBy(s => s.StudentName, d => d.Subject)
                                  .Select(grp => new { StudentName = grp.Key, Subjects = grp.ToList() })
                                  .ToList();
```

Then you can use the projection above to display it however you want. Something like this maybe:

```
foreach (var grouping in StudentsAndCurrentSubjects) {
    var studentName = grouping.StudentName;
    var subjects = string.Join(", ", grouping.Subjects);
    Console.WriteLine($"{studentName}\t{subjects}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a `GroupJoin` by using the `into` keyword.

```
var studentsAndCurrentSubjects = (
  from student in lstStudents
  join enrollment in lstEnrolled
    on student equals enrollment.Student
    into enrollments
  join drop in lstDrop
    on student equals drop.Student
    into drops
  let classes = enrollments.Select(e => e.Subject).Except(drops.Select(d => d.Subject))
  select new
  {
    Student = student.StudentName,
    Subjects = string.Join(", ", classes)
  })
  .ToList();
```

Or, you can subquery with `let`.  This will have noticeably slower performance against larger lists than the other solution, but it should be fine in the database.

```
var studentsAndCurrentSubjects = (
  from student in lstStudents
  let enrollments = lstEnrolled.Where(x => student == x.Student).Select(x => x.Subject)
  let drops = lstDrops.Where(x => student == drop.Student).Select(x => x.Subject)
  let classes = enrollments.Except(drops)
  select new
  {
    Student = student.StudentName,
    Subjects = string.Join(", ", classes)
  })
  .ToList();
```